# How to create a join between 2 tables where the date from the second table should be between 2 consecutive dates from the first table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables and I need to create a join between them:

Table 1:

| Session | Player | Date Start |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | A | 20 Sept 2022 13:25 |
| 1234 | A | 20 Sept 2022 14:23 |
| 4532 | B | 20 Sept 2022 14:43 |
| 4532 | B | 20 Sept 2022 14:46 |
| 1234 | A | 20 Sept 2022 14:50 |
| 1456 | A | 20 Sept 2022 16:24 |
| 1456 | A | 20 Sept 2022 16:48 |

Table 2:

| Session | Player | Date End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | A | 20 Sept 2022 13:28 |
| 1234 | A | 20 Sept 2022 14:30 |
| 4532 | B | 20 Sept 2022 14:45 |
| 4532 | B | 20 Sept 2022 14:49 |
| 1234 | A | 20 Sept 2022 14:52 |
| 1456 | A | 20 Sept 2022 16:29 |
| 1456 | A | 20 Sept 2022 16:49 |

The Date End should be between 2 consecutive Date Start for the same session and player

| Session | Player | Date Start | Date End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | A | 20 Sept 2022 13:25 | 20 Sept 2022 13:28 |
| 1234 | A | 20 Sept 2022 14:23 | 20 Sept 2022 14:30 |
| 4532 | B | 20 Sept 2022 14:43 | 20 Sept 2022 14:45 |
| 4532 | B | 20 Sept 2022 14:46 | 20 Sept 2022 14:49 |
| 1234 | A | 20 Sept 2022 14:50 | 20 Sept 2022 14:52 |
| 1456 | A | 20 Sept 2022 16:24 | 20 Sept 2022 16:29 |
| 1456 | A | 20 Sept 2022 16:48 | 20 Sept 2022 16:49 |

Comment: The Session value is not unique, that sucks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you can use an arbitrarily high value for the upper boundary when there isn't another row, you could use `LEAD` with a default value to create your range, and then `JOIN` with `>=` and `<`/`<=` (depends what you need) logic in the `ON`:

```sql
WITH T1 AS (
    SELECT Session,
           Player,
           DateStart,
           LEAD(DateStart,1,'99991231') OVER (PARTITION BY Session, Player ORDER BY DateStart) AS NextDateStart
    FROM dbo.Table1 T1)
SELECT T1.Session,
       T1.Player,
       T1.DateStart,
       T2.DateEnd
FROM T1
     JOIN dbo.Table2 T2 ON T1.Session = T2.Session
                       AND T1.Player = T2.Player
                       AND T1.DateStart <= T2.DateEnd
                       AND T1.NextDateStart >= T2.DateEnd;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qmwnPbC0)

Answer (score 1):

i think this query can help you, try it out.

```
with table_1 (Session,Player,Datestart)
as
(
  Select           '1234','A','2022-09-20 13:25:00.000'
  union all Select '1234','A','2022-09-20 14:23:00.000'
  union all Select '4532','B','2022-09-20 14:43:00.000'
  union all Select '4532','B','2022-09-20 14:46:00.000'
  union all Select '1234','A','2022-09-20 14:50:00.000'
  union all Select '1456','A','2022-09-20 16:24:00.000'
  union all Select '1456','A','2022-09-20 16:48:00.000'
),
table_2 (Session,Player,Dateend)
as
(
  Select           '1234','A','2022-09-20 13:28:00.000'
  union all Select '1234','A','2022-09-20 14:30:00.000'
  union all Select '4532','B','2022-09-20 14:45:00.000'
  union all Select '4532','B','2022-09-20 14:49:00.000'
  union all Select '1234','A','2022-09-20 14:52:00.000'
  union all Select '1456','A','2022-09-20 16:26:00.000'
  union all Select '1456','A','2022-09-20 16:49:00.000'
)
Select 
    x.Session,
    x.Player,
    x.Datestart,
    y.Dateend
from (
Select 
    Session,
    Player,
    Datestart,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Session,Player ORDER BY Datestart) a
FROM
    table_1
) x
inner join 
(
Select 
    Session as Session_2,
    Player as PLayer_2,
    Dateend,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Session,Player ORDER BY Dateend) b
FROM
table_2
) as y
on 
    x.Session = y.Session_2 and
    x.Player = y.PLayer_2 and
    x.a = y.b
order by 
    x.Datestart
```